# How do I make particles move from one bigger side of a cube to a smaller side of a cube without them escaping the mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, particles, collision

I'm making a tractor beam that uses an Emitter Particle System where particles spawn in the volume of a cube and always move in a straight line from left to right on the local x axis towards the smaller side. Some of the particles that spawn near the faces in the larger volume of the mesh move out of the mesh when moving on the local axis. Which is why I use a collision physics property set to kill particles collided particles, but some particles still manage to escape. Anyone know how to prevent this? Or could tell me how to make particles move only to one point, nonmatter where they spawn?
[image]

Blend File:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XZIRQorlEB8aQaWaFGMzDkNbsMWFdqce/view?usp=share_link